# system2 does not save the output of a java command line to the file system, only output in console is created

Tags: r, system2

I am trying to run a Java application (beagle2vcf) from R.

I tried with `system()` but no runs are performed only the help of the function is returned in the R console. But when I copy the same command to my `cmd` console the run is performed.

Then I try with `system2()` and only output in the console is created, but I need a file on my filesystem.

I am using the `stdout` parameter, but this does not seem to work.

Perhaps the fact that the Java application uses `">output"` to generate files plays a role? Other Java applications that do not have this syntax to output the results run fine with `system()`.

Example of command using `system()`:

```
"java -jar beagle2vcf.jar 1 OneChrom.markers beagleTrain.bgl NA Chrom1Train.vcf"
```

Example `system2` call:

```
system2(command="java",args=c("-jar","beagle2vcf.jar", j,"OneChrom.markers","beagleTrain.bgl","NA"),stdout=outnameTrainVCF,invisible=TRUE)
```

I run R3.5.0 on a windows 10 machine

The output should be a vcf file on my file system.

Comment: Thank you Rui Barradas for formatting my post (new user here, so no idea if this is the appropriate way to thank someone for this)!